# How to encoded using UTF-8 before loading data? in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I need to use the `calldata` data from the `sand` package. I used the code:

```
library(sand)
data(calldata)
head(calldata)

min.call <- min(calldata$Flow)
calldata$FlowCnt <- round(5 * calldata$Flow / min.call)
W <- xtabs(FlowCnt ~ Orig + Dest, calldata)
g.cd <- graph.adjacency(W, weighted=TRUE)

in.flow  <- graph.strength(g.cd, mode="in")
out.flow <- graph.strength(g.cd, mode="out")
vsize    <- sqrt(in.flow + out.flow) / 100
pie.vals <- lapply((1:vcount(g.cd)), function(i) c(in.flow[i], out.flow[i]))
ewidth   <- E(g.cd)$weight / 10^5
plot(g.cd, vertex.size=vsize, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=pie.vals, edge.width=ewidth, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
```

As the result I have the error on the last command `plot`:

```
(process:28394): Pango-WARNING **: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()
```

The data look like:

```
      Orig             Dest DistEuc DistRd   O.GRP     D.GRP     Flow
1 Bruck/Le             Wien   36.14     37 7828880 285193984 57.61270
2 Bruck/Le       Mistelbach   61.46     81 7828880   7685130  1.39963
3 Bruck/Le      Wr.Neustadt   46.50     56 7828880  27369776 19.90791
4 Bruck/Le St.P<U+00BA>lten   88.60     96 7828880  24601360  3.90906
5 Bruck/Le           Zwettl  135.13    145 7828880   8143690  1.38712
6 Bruck/Le       Hollabrunn   78.75     85 7828880   6385840  1.49779
```

I think the reason of problem is UTF-8 characters like in the 4th line `<U+00BA>`.

**Question.**

How to encoded using UTF-8 before loading data?

Comment: @MarcoSandri I am using the https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: @MarcoSandri, sorry. I added the full code.

Comment: Try adding `calldata$Orig <- iconv(calldata$Orig, "latin1", "ASCII")` and
`calldata$Dest <- iconv(calldata$Dest, "latin1", "ASCII")` after the first 2 lines.